# Vim 8.1 syntax highlighting has disappeared

Tags: vim

I use script files with gvim to set syntax to html for files that don't have the extension 'html', but which contain html.
Eg script file contains 'set syntax=html'.
When file is edited: gvim -S scriptfile.txt myfile.txt, the syntax highlighting no longer appears.   I say 'no longer' because I've been doing this for years and suddenly (Win10, Vim 8.1) it has stopped...    Within the edit, ':set' returns 'syntax=html' - but no syntax highlighting.    Must have screwed up something subtle, but what?   Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Went back to the default "c:\Program Files (x86)\vim_vimrc", instead of copying mswin.vim to that location.  All's well.